# Selenium: Unable to enter text into iframe

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, iframe

I'm using the following Java function to enter text into an iframe:

```
public boolean EnterTextIntoFrame() 
{
    String text=this.data; // String to be entered
    boolean result=true;
    try{
        if(keyType.equals("xpath"))
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            WebElement ifr=driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(keyValue)));

            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame(ifr);
            // Author: Ruchir Sharma; 17/3/2015
            if(driver instanceof FirefoxDriver)
            {
                WebElement ckeContent = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
                ckeContent.clear();
                ckeContent.sendKeys(text);
            }
            // Author: Ruchir Sharma; 17/3/2015
            if(driver instanceof ChromeDriver)
            {
                WebElement ckeContent = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")); 
                ckeContent.clear(); 
                ckeContent.sendKeys(text); 
            }
            else
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML=arguments[0];",text,"");
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
}
```

When I run the above code, instead of entering the string 'text' into the iframe, my code enters the string "undefined".Please help.

Comment: Which code branch is being executed? Firefox, Chrome or Other?

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm running this script on FireFox. There's no syntax error as such.

Comment: What is `body`? I'd have guessed it was the `<body></body>` element, to which you can't send keys.

Comment: @AndyTurner The xpath for my iframe is: //*[@id='cke_rfp_letter']/div/div/iframe. Is this causing some issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last line of your question after the code? If string is still appearing it is likely that the variable text contains the string value of "undefined". What happens if you state String text = "text"?

Comment: @bagelmakers 'text' is getting value from 'this.data', which in my case is: "This is test data". I'm nowhere using the string 'undefined'.